# PostGIS: intersection of a polygon with 2 rasters

Tags: postgis, raster, polygon, intersection

I'm trying to get the intersection of a Polygon with 2 raster layers in PostGIS.

The rasters have the same size and pixel size and I'd like to retrieve for the polygon a list of something like that:

1; 2
1; 2
1; 3
2; 2
...

Where each line is a pixel intersected by the polygon in both layers and the values is a combination of the pixel value from raster 1 and the pixel value from raster 2.

I don't really know what kind of request I have to do to achieve that...

**EDIT**: Maybe this query can answer my question:

```
SELECT 
    ST_DumpValues(ST_Clip(nh.rast, 1, geom, true), 1, false),
    ST_DumpValues(ST_Clip(nt.rast, 1, geom, true), 1, false) 
FROM 
    niv_hydrique AS nh,
    niv_trophique AS nt,
    ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('%s', %s), 31370) AS geom 
WHERE 
    ST_Intersects(nh.rast, geom) AND ST_Intersects(nt.rast, geom)
```

Where *niv_hydrique*, *niv_trophique* are my 2 rasters and I construct my polygon from a WKT representation.

I can then programmatically extract the values for each pixel in the two 2-dim arrays returned.

Comment: What have you tried so far (e.g. queries)? What about UNION two intersection queries? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-union.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've edited my message to add an attempt of solution.

Comment: And what happens when you run this query? I am guessing it works, but you want to intersperse the two sets for dumped values into one result set?

Comment: It returns something like {{0, 2}, {2, 0}} and {{0,4}, {4, 0}} (2x2 pixels) that I can easily combine with Python into (0,0);(2,4);(2,4);(0,0) which is what I want.